Errors while starting vite + react
I am making a fullstack project, I have a parent folder in which I have frontend and backend folder. Frontend folder is my Vite project but when I do npm run dev it just shows errors:
> frontend@0.0.0 dev
> vite

✘ [ERROR] Expected identifier but found "import"

    (define name):1:0:
      1 │ import.meta.dirname
        ╵ ~~~~~~

✘ [ERROR] Expected identifier but found "import"

    (define name):1:0:
      1 │ import.meta.filename
        ╵ ~~~~~~

✘ [ERROR] Expected identifier but found "import"

    (define name):1:0:
      1 │ import.meta.url
        ╵ ~~~~~~

failed to load config from /home/pankaj/study/sneaker-project/frontend/vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error: Build failed with 3 errors:
(define name):1:0: ERROR: Expected identifier but found "import"
(define name):1:0: ERROR: Expected identifier but found "import"
(define name):1:0: ERROR: Expected identifier but found "import"
    at failureErrorWithLog (/home/pankaj/study/sneaker-project/frontend/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1476:15)
    at /home/pankaj/study/sneaker-project/frontend/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:945:25
    at runOnEndCallbacks (/home/pankaj/study/sneaker-project/frontend/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1316:45)
    at buildResponseToResult (/home/pankaj/study/sneaker-project/frontend/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:943:7)
    at /home/pankaj/study/sneaker-project/frontend/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:970:16
    at responseCallbacks.<computed> (/home/pankaj/study/sneaker-project/frontend/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:622:9)
    at handleIncomingPacket (/home/pankaj/study/sneaker-project/frontend/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:677:12)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (/home/pankaj/study/sneaker-project/frontend/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:600:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:524:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:561:12)


I have the same problem with vue. I simply created a new app with npm create vue@latest, then ran npm install in the project folder and got all my dependencies fine. Then tried npm run dev to see the box app and boom, got what you have.

https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/19018

Step 1: npm i -D esbuild@0.24.0
Step 2: npm i
Step 3: npm run dev

This didn't work for me in a Svelte project, same error message.  Used the npx sv create command..

By following this Github issue and adding the esbuild version to overrides I got it working - https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/19018

I am having the same error with laravel project. Looks like "vite": "^6.0.4" is causing the issue. Downgrading works at this moment
npm uninstall vite

npm install vite@^5


Worked for me as well. Tried multiple things but downgrading using the same steps was the solution

I tried a lot to solve this with ChatGPT but finally a human answer solved it!!

Worked also for me Pal! Issue was with Vite version 6. Downgraded to v5.4.11 and then run npm run dev It will work!

Any clue why this happens? I have a project that has Vite 6 and it runs normally. Then on a different project it doesn't ... weird.

this works thanks but I did not why this sudden vite failed

its because of regression in vite's dependency esbuild v0.24.1, your previous Vite 6 installation would have had esbuild@0.24.0 or lower and thats why its not happening. Maintainers of package are working on a fix.

Vite 6.0.5 has been released. It fixes this issue by pinning esbuild to v0.24.0 for the time being.

Downgrade with
npm i -D esbuild@0.24.0


I encountered a similar issue caused by esbuild@0.24.1. This version seems to have compatibility problems with certain project configurations. The solution I found is to pin the esbuild version to 0.24.0, which works well. You can do this by running:
npm install --save-dev esbuild@0.24.0

If you’d like to ensure that all your projects use a safe version of esbuild, you can add a dependency resolution in your package.json file:
"devDependencies": {
   ...
   "esbuild": "0.24.0",
   ...
}


Your issue seems to be related to the recent release of esbuild version 0.24.1.
To resolve the issue, downgrade esbuild to a stable version:
npm i -D esbuild@0.24.0

This should fix the error you are experiencing when running npm run dev.
For more details, see the related GitHub issue: esbuild issue #4012.

A change in esbuild 0.24.1 is affecting Vite's config loader : https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/4010
pnpm overrides:
  "pnpm": {
    "overrides": {
      "esbuild": "0.24.0"
    }
  }

npm overrides:
{
  "overrides": {
    "esbuild": "0.24.0"
  }
}

yarn resolutions:
{
  "resolutions": {
    "esbuild": "0.24.0"
  }
}


By @sapphi-red from git : https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/19018#issuecomment-2556490184


Confirmed.  Down grading to 5.4.11 solves issue.  However, I am able to successfully build some projects with 6.0.4.
package.json:
 "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "lucide-react": "0.468.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "4.3.4",
    "vite": "6.0.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "recoil": "^0.7.7",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0"
  }

    $ npm run build

> recoil-state-visualizer@0.1.0 build
> vite build

vite v6.0.4 building for production...
✓ 1592 modules transformed.
dist/index.es.js  63.14 kB │ gzip: 15.92 kB
dist/index.umd.js  43.72 kB │ gzip: 13.77 kB
✓ built in 2.25s

